# Java library method to find an item in a collection AND check if there was exactly one match

Tags: search, collections, java, iterable

Does any common Java library provide a method to *find an element in a finite collection* **and** *ensure that there was exactly one match*?

The method could, for example, return `null` if nothing was found and throw an exception if multiple elements were found.

Currently I use my own Implementation (see below), but I'd rather not pollute business code with such utility methods (even if extracted in a separate utility package).

I also *don't* want the overhead of iterating over collection more than once, or an overhead of filtering collection and looking at the length of the result.

P.S. my current solution (which works, but is to be replaced with a library method):

```
public static <T> T getSingleMatch(Iterable<T> lookIn, com.google.common.base.Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    T foundItem = null;
    for (T item : lookIn) {
        if (predicate.apply(item)) {
            if (foundItem != null) 
                throw new RuntimeException("multiple matches"); // alternatively: `return null;` 
            else 
                foundItem = item;
        }
    }
    // alternatively: `if (foundItem == null) throw ...`
    return foundItem;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? Without more information, it looks like you should rather be using a `Set` in the first place. The behaviour would change to thrown an exception on insertion (of course it is you who has to check the return value of `add`). Or you could use a MultiSet. Or is it a requirement to work on all sorts of Iterables?

Comment: @Axel: Thanks for your suggestion. I receive an `Iterable` from an external interface; it may well contain multiple elements which match some criteria (complex ones — not just `.equals()`), and it is not allowed by the business logic (==> `RuntimeException`). The 3rdparty library actually returns an `ArrayList` *in its current implementation*, but I don't want to rely on that. Number of elements may be very large, and all I need is to extract a single element — that's why I don't want an overhead of building a `Set` just for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to separate out the two ideas into two methods, so that each method does one thing - then combine the calls

- One method to *lazily* filter, returning a sequence of matching results
- One method to return an item from a sequence, requiring it to be the only item

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has both of those:

- [`Iterables.filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) to filter lazily
- [`Iterables.getOnlyElement`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getOnlyElement%28java.lang.Iterable%29) to return the sole element of a sequence

So for example:

```
String match = Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.filter(source, predicate));
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `Iterables.getOnlyElement`, that's exactly what I need. I should somehow find time to take a better look at Guava...

Comment: @AlexShesterov: Yes, Guava is lovely :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = collection.indexOf(item);
if (index != -1 && index == collection.lastIndexOf(item)) {
    // one and only one
}
```

If `index != -1` it means no such item. If the next if statement doesn't evaluate to true it means that there are at least 2 items. You can restructure it to throw exceptions, return null or return the index or item. I trust you know how to do this based on your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer; though this wouldn't work for `Iterables`, 
it is definitely a very nice solution for `Collection`s; +1.

Comment: Right, I did however assume you meant collection because you wrote that initially, but your method signature was iterable and I thought that was just to keep an even higher interface type and not something you really needed. Also, I think my code will actually traverse the collection twice if at least one item exists (although it will stop fast if item found on each end).

Comment: Hey, if you decide to use a Collection any way, there's a frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)

Comment: no, you method actually *won't* traverse the collection twice, it will go over the collection from the beginning; if nothing found, it finishes (1 complete traversal). If found, it stops at the element (not iterating to the end) and goes over the collection from the end, stopping *not later than* at the same element (1 complete or incomplete traversal altogether). So by the performance criterion, you method is great :)

Comment: If it's a singly linked list it has to go from beginning to item for the first call, and again for the next call.

Comment: yes, but does anybody use single linked lists in real Java applications? :)

Comment: I hope not. :) But Collection<?> could be one.